# Parsing BitPay Rates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm having difficulty parsing BitPay's JSON API, specifically the [/api/rates](https://bitpay.com/api/rates) endpoint.

I have the following:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
data = JSON.parse(open("https://bitpay.com/api/rates").read)
```

The only problem is that it's not really nested, and I can't do something like `data["USD"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the whole array and search for the currency you want

```
data.select { |curr| curr["code"] == "USD" }[0]["rate"]
```

Replace `"USD"` with which currency rate you want.